# Multiple domains with nginx reverse proxy in Centos7

Tags: nginx, proxy, dns, reverse

I want to host multiple domains on same server using nginx front reverse proxy but I am getting error: "This site can't be reached domain1.example.com server DNS address could not be found". I can reach maindomain.example.com but not other 2 domains: domain1.example.com and domain2.example.com. Below is my maindomain.example.com.conf config file.

```
server {
            listen          80 default;
            server_name     maindomain.example.com;
         return 301      https://$host$request_uri;
    }

server {
            listen 80;
            listen 443 ssl;
            server_name domain1.example.com;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/maindomain.example.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/maindomain.example.com.key;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header                Host                    $host:$server_port;
            proxy_set_header                X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header                X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header                X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;
            proxy_pass                      http://localhost:8085;

            proxy_redirect                  http://127.0.0.1:8085   $scheme://domain1.example.com;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name domain2.example.com;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/maindomain.example.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/maindomain.example.com.key;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header                Host                    $host:$server_port;
                proxy_set_header                X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header                X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header                X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;
                proxy_pass                      http://localhost:9009;

                proxy_redirect                  http://127.0.0.1:9009   $scheme://domain2.example.com;


    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a server configuration issue. Check the DNS settings for example.com.

Comment: Thank you so much. That helped.